# Workbook instance is active even after closing it manually

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am adding  workbook to the workbooks programmatically thru macro.

when i close the newly created workbook manually,then try to run the code then i am facing issue like "Automation Error" or "WorkBook_ Activation failed" .

Please how can i solve the issue.

My Code is below:

```
    Const durationPeriod = 90
Dim trendsFile As Workbook
Dim trendsSheet As Worksheet
Dim workSheetOpen As Boolean



Option Explicit



Sub SASTrend()

' this routine looks at the organization in the currently highlight cell and creates a 90 day user and usage trend graph

Dim customerName As String
Dim duration As Integer
Dim weeklySheetName As String

Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
Dim dayOfWeek As Integer

    On Error GoTo errorHandling

    customerName = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (ActiveCell.row)).Value

    ' calculate the first week of the duration period. Usage trends sheets are always on Saturdays
    ' and are updated on Sunday night / Monday morning

    startDate = Date - durationPeriod
    dayOfWeek = Weekday(startDate)
    startDate = startDate + (vbSaturday - dayOfWeek)

    ' we want to report up to the most recent Saturday. By taking current date -1
    ' we make sure we get the most recent Saturday assuming it is run M-F

    endDate = Date - 1

    Dim usageTracking As Worksheet
    Dim dataFound As Boolean
    dataFound = False


    ' get a reference to Usage Tracking sheet to be able to switch focus

    Set usageTracking = Worksheets("Usage Tracking")

    While startDate < (endDate)

        Dim weeklyUsers As Double
        Dim weeklyMinutes As Double
        Dim rowNumber As Integer


        ' walk the weekly sheets and gather usage data for graphing

        ' make sure usage tracking is the active worksheet

        usageTracking.Activate

        ' buld sheet name

        weeklySheetName = "SAS-" + Format(startDate, "mm") + Format(startDate, "dd")

        ' get the number of users for the specified week

        weeklyUsers = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(weeklySheetName).Range("B:B"), customerName)

        ' get the total minutes for the specified week

        weeklyMinutes = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Worksheets(weeklySheetName).Range("B:B"), customerName, Worksheets(weeklySheetName).Range("D:D"))


        ' check to make sure we have non-zero data before creating graph / worksheet

        If (weeklyUsers > 0 Or weeklyMinutes > 0) And dataFound = False Then

            ' create a new workbook to hold the trend sheets


          If trendsFile Is Nothing Then

             Set trendsFile = Workbooks.Add()
             trendsFile.Activate
             Set trendsSheet = trendsFile.ActiveSheet

            Else

                ' add a new sheet to the trends workbook

                trendsFile.Activate
                Set trendsSheet = Sheets.Add

            End If

            dataFound = True
            rowNumber = 1
            trendsSheet.Name = Left(customerName, 10) + " " + Format(Date, "MMDD")
            trendsSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 1) = "Week Ending"
            trendsSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 2) = "Users"
            trendsSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 3) = "Minutes"
            rowNumber = rowNumber + 1

        End If

        ' if a sheet has been created, then we have at least one non-zero value so add data

        If dataFound = True Then
            trendsSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 1) = startDate
            trendsSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 2) = weeklyUsers
            trendsSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 3) = weeklyMinutes
            rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
        End If


        startDate = startDate + 7



    Wend

    ' if we have data, create the chart

    If dataFound = True Then

        ' make sure the trends sheet is active for chart insertion

        trendsSheet.Activate

        Dim chtChart As ChartObject
        Dim chartName As String
        Dim endRange As String

        ' define the end of the range for the chart

        endRange = "C" & CStr(rowNumber - 1)


        ' add chart to current sheet

        Set chtChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Top:=200, Width:=900, Height:=400)
        chtChart.Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineStacked
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=trendsSheet.Range("A1", endRange)
        ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = customerName
        ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (5)


    Else
        MsgBox ("No usage data found for customer " + customerName)
    End If

'    Set trendsSheet = Nothing
'    Set trendsFile = Nothing

    Exit Sub

errorHandling:
    MsgBox (Err.Description)



End Sub
```

I am thinking the issue is trendsfile instance is active even though i closed manually.

When debugged to see, it is hitting to  the else part even though the 
trendsfile is closed.

How can i make sure it is opened correctly

Comment: How are you closing a workbook that you have added programmatically before the code ends? Can you provide the full code (i.e. from `Sub` to `End Sub`?

Comment: I have edited  with full code

Comment: That won't run coz as soon as I try to compile it gives an error that **Option Explicit** is invalid within a procedure.

Comment: So trendsFile is a Public variable which gets Set where? It's not set within the code provided.

Comment: I am not facing any error.Create a new module and try to copy the entire code.I am not facing nay issue it is compiling and working fine except for the issue I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

Set any objects referencing the old Workbook to Nothing after the end of the Macro:

```
Set trendsSheet = Nothing
Set trendsFile = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.it is working.If the trendsfile is open,when user clicks on my macro  then  another trendssheet should get added tot he current  trendsfile.How can i check if it trendsfile is close then set trendsfile instance is nothing

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't `Set trendsFile = Workbooks('SomeWorkbook") before testing`If trendsFile =Nothing`

When you test `If trendsFile =Nothing` it does so your IF statement falls straight through to ELSE

Comment: WorkBook name is dynamic.it will be the default name like "Book1.xls","Book2.xls"...

Comment: The workbook **object** will only be `NOTHING` **until you add it.** Change your `If trendsFile Is Nothing Then
` to `If **Not**trendsFile Is Nothing Then`

Comment: if i do this, every time it is creating a new one.                                              i want in such a way if work book is present add worksheet to the existing.if work book is not there create a new one with worksheet